# Unable to run oracle report 11g

Tags: weblogic-10.x, oraclereports

I have installed `oracle reports 11g` with `weblogic server` and `oracle database 11g.`

I have developed simple report and try to run it,It run fine if report .rdf file placed in local drive.

But if change the location of report .rdf file local to shared drive it can't run.

It gives an error:

```
REP-110: File report.rdf cannot be opened.
REP-1070: An error occurred while opening or saving a document.
REP-0110: File report.rdf cannot be opened.
```

I have also changed report path to shared drive.But still not working.

I do not know,what is problem with running the report from shared drive.
So how to run it?

Comment: How about the rights of shared drive? Do you checked them? I have the similar problem in past, in my local testing environment everything worked perfect with shared drive. In clients testing environment was the same problem, as you facing now. And I think they did something with rights.

Comment: I can run form from shared drive.only report get problem